# aws emr with glue: how to specify database name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I'm trying to run a hive job using Glue metadata. From the aws docs

> Under AWS Glue Data Catalog settings select Use for Hive table
>   metadata.

I created a cluster that apparently connects to the `default` database from glue (i can tell by running `show tables;` from hive, which lists a table from `default`database.

Now does anyone know how to provide an option to connect to another database from glue ? The only thing I could find in the docs is the opportunity of providing a `hive.metastore.glue.catalogid` where you can provide a catalog from another account, but I cannot find anything in the docs about using the right database.

Or perhaps all the databases are loaded. If so, do you know how to access them within hive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out all the databases are loaded in hive. You can simply access them by using `select * from my_database_name.my_table_name`, or by setting the database name once with `use my_database_name`